# How to load a WFS layer using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, wfs, qgsvectorlayer

I have written the following code based on the PyQGIS Developer's Cookbook and other sources, however I can't get the WFS layer to load. The layer returns False on a validation check. I'm at a loss for what the issue could be, as the WFS layer loads fine via the interface "Add Layer" menu. I would use that approach but I need to query this WFS layer within a script. Can anyone offer insight here?

```
uri = 'url=https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/sites-of-special-scientific-interest-england/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=ms:Sites_of_Special_Scientific_Interest_England&SRSNAME=EPSG:27700&InvertAxisOrientation=1'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "WFS_Layer" , 'WFS')
print(layer.isValid())
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.addMapLayer(layer)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I run your code, it returns `False` same result as yours, but when I removed the `url=` before the link it works and return `True`:

```
uri = 'https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/sites-of-special-scientific-interest-england/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=ms:Sites_of_Special_Scientific_Interest_England&SRSNAME=EPSG:27700&InvertAxisOrientation=1'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "WFS_Layer" , 'WFS')
print(layer.isValid())
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.addMapLayer(layer)
```

[image]